# Reading SSIS variable in Custom Pipeline Component

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to read package variables in a custom PipelineComponent

```
public override void PreExecute()
{
            IDTSVariable100 vars2 = null;
            VariableDispenser.LockForRead("System::databse");
            VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out vars2);
}
```

VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out vars2) gives me error that

```
"The best overloaded method match for 
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariableDispenser100.GetVariables(out Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100)' 
 has some invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apart from the fact that the `IDTSVariableDispenser100` interface is one of those APIs that "[supports the SQL Server infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522739.aspx)", you've declared `vars2` to be of the wrong type. The [IDTSVariableDispenser100.GetVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.idtsvariabledispenser100.getvariables.aspx) method takes an `out` parameter of type `IDTSVariables100`, not `IDTSVariable100`. (Note the "s".)